# Liferay + Spring : @ModelAttribute in render method with url parameters

Tags: java, spring, liferay

I want to make portlet with filter and search results. filter have to be send in get method.
I`m using spring annotation @ModelAttribute for filter. But all properties in filter are null, because liferay use prefix for url parameters like _[PORTLET_NAME]_WAR_[WAR_NAME].
I used actionRequest and sended filter by post method and it workek, but i need parameters in url.

Method in controller:

```
@RequestMapping
public String view(@ModelAttribute("filter") ProcessSearchFilter filter, RenderRequest request, Model model)
```

when parameter name is _processSearch_WAR_portlets_text=test, in filter property text is test, but i want use just text parameter in url.

any idea how it make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **Liferay 6.2** it is necessary to declare name-space prefixes for the fields on your view page. If you are not recieving any values from the submitted form, then try either setting the prefixes like this

```
<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace />inputTextName" />
```

or changing the settings of your portlet so it doesn't require them. In `liferay-portlet.xml` set the **requires-namespaced-parameters** tag to **false** for the selected portlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "text" parameter in url then you can use, instead if @ModelAttribute

```
@RequestParam("text") String text
```

or, if param variable name is same as parameter name

```
@RequestParam String text
```

Also note that @RequestParam, as shown above, makes parameter required by default. If this is not wanted use

```
@RequestParam(value = "text", required = false) String text
```

Your render method should (also) have @RenderMapping annotation.